# SecurityLists appearing incomplete

Tags: fix-protocol

I am receiving incomplete SecurityLists from a venue. Here is the message I am receiving:

8=FIXT.1.1|9=112|35=y|34=9|49=xxx|52=20130913-11:17:37.418|56=xxx|146=1|020001=20130913-11:17:37.402|10=108
(I have deleted the COMPID's)

I have tried reordering the repeating groups fields in our data dictionary to match the order of the repeating group fields in the venues data dictionary.

Still having no luck!

Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried to correct the formatting of your message and add visible field separators ("|").  Looks like you messed up the part after 146=1, though, as 020001 is not a real tag.  If you get a minute, please fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You're using QuickFIX, right?

If yes, I'm guessing that you are missing `UseDataDictionary=Y` and/or `DataDictionary=path/to/your/dd`.  It's a common newbie mistake.

This is just a guess, though.  You really haven't given much to go on.